# Linear regression slope error in numpy

Tags: numpy, linear-regression, standard-deviation

I use numpy.polyfit to get a linear regression: coeffs = np.polyfit(x, y, 1).

What is the best way to calculate the error of the fit's slope using numpy?

Comment: When you use `polyfit`, it returns the residuals of the fit. You can do a Chi2 on this to get the goodness of fit which I assume is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am looking for the absolute error, not a goodness.

Comment: The residuals are the absolute error for each point in the fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already mentioned by @ebarr in the comments, you can use np.polyfit to return the residuals by using the keyword argument `full=True`.

Example:

```
x = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  4.0,  5.0])
y = np.array([0.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, -0.8, -1.0])
z, residuals, rank, singular_values, rcond = np.polyfit(x, y, 3, full=True)
```

`residuals` then is the sum of least squares.

Alternatively, you can use the keyword argument `cov=True` to get the covariance matrix.

Example:

```
x = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  4.0,  5.0])
y = np.array([0.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, -0.8, -1.0])
z, cov = np.polyfit(x, y, 3, cov=True)
```

Then, the diagonal elements of `cov` are the variances of the coefficients in z, i.e. `np.sqrt(np.diag(cov))` gives you the standard deviations of the coefficients. You can use the standard deviations to estimate the probability that the absolute error exceeds a certain value, e.g. by inserting the standard deviations in the [uncertainty propagation calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty). If you use e.g. 3*standard deviations in the uncertainty propagation, you calculate the error which will not be exceeded in 99.7% of the cases.

One last hint: you have to choose whether you choose `full=True` or `cov=True`. `cov=True` only works when `full=False` (default) or vice versa.

Comment: When I try to implement this solution, I get negative values along the diagonal of the co-variate matrix.